# How to configure sync folders in Qnap and NAS?

Tags: backup, sync, nas, qnap

I have a NAS and Qnap as a manager, so I can't figure out how to change the way to sync folders between NAS and Qsync.

I need to change the sync folders to sync in other locations

Taking some other folder in PC like:

.C

..Projects

...Work

"Work" meaning the main folder the user is saving the files

Saving the folder inside the NAS following this:

.Root

..Organization

...User

....Backup

Making backup the main folder to sync the files.

How do I achieve this goal?